# Limiting NSTableView to two selections

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview

I am wondering if anyone has a method to limiting the number of selections allowed in an NSTableView to 2 concurrent selections. I am trying to calculate the delta between two selected values and would like for it to only select two at a time.

I was thinking of trying to keep track of what has been selected so that I can programmatically unselect anything if the selection expands above two, but this seems kludgy and possibly not as easy as it sounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the delegate method `tableView:shouldSelectRow:` and return NO if you don't think the user should be allowed to select the row. For any reason you decide - for instance because the number of selected rows is already 2.

To get the number of currently selected rows at any given time, just call `selectedRowIndexes` on the *table view* (not the delegate, nor data source). This will give you an `NSIndexSet`, which has a `count` method with the information you are looking for.

The index set also holds the information about the other row indexes already selected, in case you want to deselect them.

Not knowing anything about the app, the user experience sounds a bit... strange. It is easy enough to implement, though, so no harm done in trying it out.

Comment: There is no tableView:shouldSelectRow: delegate method

Comment: Thanks Monolo, I had just discovered this and was answering my own question while you posted this :)

Answer (score 0):

In your Table View's delegate you can implement `-[<NSTableViewDelegate> tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)]`

Maybe something like this:

```
- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    switch ([notification.object numberOfSelectedRows]) {
        case 0: break; // Nothing is selected
        case 1: break; // Only one row selected
        case 2: break; // Two rows
        default:
           ... unselect rows ...
           break;
    }
}
```

Of course you can also use an `if` statement. Maybe you also want to store in which order the rows are clicked—this could be done in the cases one and two.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for coming up with something to help jog my brain into the right direction. I started exploring the `NSTableViewDelegate` a little bit more hoping to find something to help with this and re-read this method: `tableView:shouldSelectRow` and it allows me to permit or reject the row selection. So now I can simply reject selecting a third row provided I have 2 already selected:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView shouldSelectRow:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    BOOL returnValue = YES;

    if (_timeStampList.selectedRowIndexes.count >= 2)
        returnValue = NO;

    return returnValue;
}
```

I'll have to work on it some more to get exactly the behavior I want because with this small snippet it just rejects the user from selecting anything more; kind of abrupt about it too. So I'll probably add some more code to allow the user to select a new row while auto-un-selecting something else.

Thanks again!

Comment: Was writing this as Monolo was posting his answer :o